# New Hard Drive Install Failure

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, hdd

I have a problem with my 2012 Macbook Pro, I'm trying to install a new WD Black 750 GB SATA III 7200 RPM in it. The problem is when I try to reinstall OS X Mountain Lion, it didn't find the drive I just installed. When I try to erase all the data from it and turn it into an OS X extended file format, Disk Utility returns  an error saying that it couldn't format it. I'm really stuck right here, has anyone else encountered the same problem and know how to resolve or get around it? Any answer will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Can you verify the HDD is not broken?

Comment: Nope not really, i presume it is not, because it is brand new. But if you have any suggestions for how to check it, i will be glad to test them. Thank you.

Comment: In Disk Utility you should be able to click on the partition and then click the Disk First Aid

Comment: I can't click on it :8.

Comment: that drive is not new, get replacement.

Comment: If you have another Mac (most ppl do not) then you could use Target Disk mode to verify. or if you have a bootable USB with OS X on it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to put a GUID partition table on the disk first - and then create a single Mac OS X Extended Journaled partition for OS X.

Comment: It didn't work, i still got an error, but this time the error is : scan data volume failed to prevent future accidental research. Don't know were it come from ?

Comment: I assume you error message is a translation, so the English error message would be "Wiping volume data to prevent future accidental probing failed"?
In that case, you probably have a faulty drive or cable - or somehow you have the disk in a read-only state. Perhaps this can be caused by wrong jumper settings on the actual drive.